# Shutil is making two copies in the destination folder

Tags: python, file-io, directory, shutil, os.walk

I have a script that is supposed to go into folders down to the last file and detect if files name have the word protein in it, if so then move the said files to a designated destination folder.

It is doing what I was hoping it would and then some more. It is making two copies each file in the destination folder, one file has the original name and the second file (the copy) has a truncated name but is the same exact file.

Can't tell what's going on. Can anyone help me?

```
import os
import shutil

def main():
    keyword = 'PROTEIN'
    final_destination ='./These_are_your_protein_files'
    location = os.getcwd()
    list_of_files = os.listdir(location)
    if not('These_are_your_protein_files' in list_of_files):
        make_destination = './These_are_your_protein_files'
        os.mkdir(make_destination)
    exclude = ['These_are_your_protein_files']
    for root_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(location, topdown=True):
        dir_names[:] = [d for d in dir_names if d not in exclude]
        for file_name in file_names:
            file_path = os.path.join(root_path, file_name)
            file_path_upper = file_path.upper()
            if keyword in file_path_upper:
                shutil.copy(file_path,final_destination)
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I tried the code it's just copy the file that have word protein in it one time.
- maybe you have more than copy of that file .
- you can check that by print the file path as follows

`if keyword in file_path_upper:print(file_path)`